# Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to put data into an MySQL table, but I get one of the following error messages:

```
    Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/ng/it/_o/ngit.org.uk/public_html/applicationform.php on line 70
```

this is how my code looks like:

```
    $myconnection = mysqli_connect('cust-mysql-123-20','register','London2014');
    mysqli_select_db($myconnection,$register );
    $query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM `application`";
    $Recordset1 = mysqli_query($myconnection, $register) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
    $totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
```

this is line 70:

```
    $Recordset1 = mysqli_query($myconnection, $register) or die(mysql_error());
```

Help please.

Comment: There's nothing remotely here that puts stuff into a table.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is contained in the variable named `$query_Recordset1` not `$register`. You're also mixing mysqli and mysql functions:

```
$myconnection = mysqli_connect('xxxxxxxx','xxxxxx','xxxxxx');
mysqli_select_db($myconnection,$register );
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM `application`";
$Recordset1 = mysqli_query($myconnection, $query_Recordset1 ) or die(mysqli_error($myconnection));
$row_Recordset1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysqli_num_rows($Recordset1);
```

FYI, if that is your real login and password you need to change them *now*.

Comment: i made those changes u mentioned.it didnt bring any error but it is now showing a blank page.